# Right Click to Image Causes refresh on explorer

Tags: windows-10, right-click

I'm using Windows 10. I've formatted and reinstalled Windows 10.

When I do right click to a png or jpg file, explorer.exe refreshes itself. But other file types doesn't cause that situation. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Look in Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Maintenance, pull down Maintenance and look at Reliability History. Is there an explorer stopped working error matching what you see on the screen?

Comment: Probably some module loaded into Explorer maybe even causing explorer.exe to crash and restart. If you open the Windows Event log `eventvwr` (Application) do you see any events from Windows Error Reporting about Explorer that happen at the same time as the problem?  If so, could you paste some of the text? You could also link the output of `.\Listdlls64.exe -v explorer  > modules.txt` tool here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls to the question using Pastebin for example. To see what modules of interest you have loaded.

Comment: Yes, Windows Event Log reports explorer.exe error. But I couldn't understand how I solve it

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Foxit Phantom PDF installed? Try to uninstall it. Sometimes it is the reason of the reported issue.